# How to remove a node via lxml xpath?

Tags: xpath, lxml

Suppose that an html file is loaded from stdin by the following command.

```
from lxml import html
doc = html.parse(sys.stdin, parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
```

By `doc.xpath(..)`, I got a `<p>` node (let's say it saved in a variable `p` in python) with a `<span>` node nested in it.

```
<p><span class="level-4">blah1 blah2</span> blah3 blah4</p>
```

It is easy to access `<span>` by `p.xpath('./span')`. But I'd like to convert what is left in `<p>` to text. Therefore, I'd like to exclude what is matched by an xpath (in this case, `./span`).

Is three a way to exclude objects matched by an xpath? Thanks.

Comment: So your expected output is `blah3 blah4`?

Comment: Yes. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
txt = """
<p><span class="level-4">blah1 blah2</span> blah3 blah4</p>
"""

from lxml.html import fragment_fromstring, tostring, etree
html = fragment_fromstring(txt)

etree.strip_elements(html, 'span', with_tail=False)
tostring(html)
```

Output:

```
<p> blah3 blah4</p>
```

Comment: When the input text is `<p><span class="level-4">blah1 blah2</span> blah3<span class="level-4"> blah4</span> blah5</p>`, is there a way to only strip off the first span. When there is some text before the first span, is there a way not strip anything? Thanks.